# How to solve error: type Integer is not visible

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have created an `ArrayList` but when I try to access an element in it, I keep getting the error `type Integer is not visible.` With a `Scanner` named `in`, I read input from a file and create an `array`, then an `ArrayList`:

```
int n = in.nextInt();
int[] curr = new int[n];
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    curr[i] = in.nextInt();
}
ArrayList<Integer> order = new ArrayList<>();
for (int item: curr) order.add(item);
```

However, when I try to access elements in `order` by creating an `int` variable called `idx` and running `order.get(idx)`, I keep getting the above error. How do I fix this?

Thanks,
Satya

Comment: Show the code that is causing the error.

Comment: Have you created your own class called `Integer`?

Comment: @Bohemian, no I have not created a class called Integer.

Comment: Please include the `idx` portion of your code so that we can see what you're doing. The code you provided as-is works as expected with stdin.

Comment: @NicholasK, the code in the question is what is causing the error. Specifically, the red underline is for the code `order.get(idx)`

Comment: @SatyaVejus You have not included the order.get(idx) sample within your code block. You mention that you use it, but you don't show how. Please edit your question to show the usage.

Comment: No you aren't understanding. Where are you using `idx` and `order.get(idx)` in the code? Please review your question once as it doesn't include the usage of them

Comment: I ran your code, but took input using scanner. Also tried to print an element using order.get(index) and it worked fine for me. May be you should put the exact code you are trying to run.

Comment: Make sure that you put " import java.util.*; " at the top of every file in your project. My guess is that you are somehow calling the get method on the ArrayList from a file that knows nothing about ArrayList, so Java throws an error when you try to access the get method as an Integer type.

Answer (score -1):

You can try with this code:

```
private static Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String args[]) {
    System.out.print("array length = ");
    int n = in.nextInt();
    int[] curr = new int[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        System.out.print("item"+i+" = ");
        curr[i] = in.nextInt();
    }
    ArrayList<Integer> order = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int item: curr) order.add(item);

    System.out.print("idx = ");
    int idx = in.nextInt();

    if (idx<order.size()){
        System.out.println(order.get(idx));
    } else {
        System.out.println("idm out of bounds...\n" +
                "result with modulo length of list:");
        System.out.println(order.get(idx%order.size()));
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also try with this code.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = in.nextInt();
    int[] curr = new int[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        curr[i] = in.nextInt();
    }

    ArrayList<Integer> order = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int item : curr)
        order.add(item);

    int size = order.size();

    while (true) {
        System.out.print("index= ");
        int idx = in.nextInt();

        if (idx < size) {
            System.out.println(order.get(idx));
            break;
        }
        System.out.println("Error : indexOutofBoundException");
        System.out.println("Try again!");
    }
}
```